# What is the difference between awaiting DownloadStringAsync versus awaiting a Task that wraps DownloadString?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I understanding that `WebClient` has a `DownloadStringAsync` method that can be used like

```
var result = await client.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

and I'm wondering  ow that's any different that simply doing

```
var result = await new Task<string>(() => client.DownloadString(url));
```

Comment: Second snippet will not work since your task is never starting

Comment: @taquion I thought that creating a new task makes it "hot"

Comment: No, if you want to make a task hot you could try Task.Run(your lambda) and this is awaitable.

Comment: in your case Task<string>.Run(()=>client.DownloadString(url));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you have a slight syntax error in your second sample. You should use `Task.Run` instead:

```
var result = await Task<string>.Run(() => client.DownloadString(url));
```

- The first example starts of `DownloadStringAsync` on the current thread and then frees that thread to do other work.
- The second example creates a new thread and then runs `DownloadString` synchronously on that thread.

Whether one is better then the other depends on whether the `Task` is CPU-bound. In this case, `DownloadStringAsync` is better, because it doesn't consume a thread.

`DownloadStringAsync` fires of the network-request and when it receives an interrupt from the network that the request has completed, it continues were you left of with the result received. That means that in that time, no thread was actively waiting for it.

In other cases, where the `Task` is CPU-bound, it doesn't really make a difference (bar any small overhead that may exist)

**EDIT**

As @paulo-morgado explains in his answer, when you say `DownloadStringAsync` I suppose you mean `DownloadStringTaskAsync`. The former does not return a `Task` so cannot be used with async/await. The latter is the one that can be awaited.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebClient` class predates the existence of tasks and the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175).

Therefor, pre-existing **Async** suffixed methods use the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228969) where the reply comes in the form of an event.

The replay to the [DownloadStringAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync) is received through the [DownloadCompletedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted).

Following the TAP recommendation, when this happens, TAP methods should be suffixed **TaskAsync**.

And that's what happens with the `WebClient` class.

If you want an `async-await` friendly use of the [DownloadString method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring), the [DownloadStringTaskAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync) should be used.

Comment: Good point on noticing the difference between `DownloadStringAsync` and `DownloadStringTaskAsync` I've also reflected it in my answer